# Understand derivative circuit with frequency filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, pid-controller

I am trying to understand a circuit which is part of a PID controller.  Input to (this part) of circuit is error signal (difference between target and present level). "DIF" part of circuit is supposed to provide the derivative component for PID loop correction.  Two gain factors are programmed into circuit via  two [8408](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/DAC8408.pdf) DACs.  DAC3D (left) has factor which is supposed to be a frequency rolloff value.  (As I understand  - to remove higher frequency noise,  which would give rise to large derivative correction). DAC3C value should be a derivative frequency  - over what time span we are calculating derivative component.  Both of these are specified in control software as time constants - between .01 and 1.26 seconds. I am trying to understand how this circuit really achieves (if it does...) what it is intended to do.  (Original designer is no longer around...).  The fact that outputs of two DACs are connected is particularly confusing to me.  Can anyone explain how/if this circuit achieves what it is intended to do?  Thanks.[image: Derivative circuit]

Comment: The data sheets of the DACs will inform you why two can be joined like that. It's all to do with current.